# Filemaker php api addFindCriterion with record id

Tags: php, filemaker

I am trying to find the record using recordId in Filemaker but getting exception as `Field is missing` Here is the query I have used

```
$query->addFindCriterion('recordId', 12);
```

Any other alternate way to query the record using record id

Answer (score 0):

getRecordById(LayoutName, RecordId)

~jens

Comment: You don't understand my question. This will return only one result. Consider RecordId as foreign key

Comment: Then you need a field 'recordId', do you have that?

Comment: You don't understand the recordId :)